# Audit trough AOP all public methods of an annotated class

Tags: aop, aspectj

There is a possibility to audit trough AOP(using spring aop, aspectj etc.) all the public methods of a class annotated with @Service or @Repository or what ever annotation I consider that is class level and not at method level?
I want to have something like this:

```java
@Pointcut(value = "execution(public * *(..))")
public void anyPublicMethod() {} 

@Around("anyPublicMethod() && @annotation(Repository)")
public Object doLogTime(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
    //do something
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pointcut should be

```java
execution(public * @my.package.Repository *.*(..))
```

which is implicitly the same as

```java
execution(public * (@my.package.Repository *).*(..))
```

P.S.: Your pointcut from the question actually targets methods annotated by `@Repository`, which is not what you want.

Comment: I  really wanted the repository annotation , but also I wanted my custom annotation. Somehow I messed things and I didn't putted the right regex . Now I have another problem: I want a conditional point-cut like @Pointcut(" if()")
         public boolean activateAspect() {
           return true; //this is just for testing, the return true will be replaced with a boolean variable
         }  and the compiler throws an exception saying: Pointcut expression ' if()' contains unsupported pointcut primitive 'if' - is that because spring AOP doesn't support conditional point-cuts?

Comment: Welcome. Please accept and upvote my answer then. BTW, pointcut expressions with joker characters are *not* regular expressions. As for your other problem, you should have posted a new question. But because the answer is simple, I am making an exception: Spring AOP does not support `if()`, only AspectJ does. This is documented [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html#aop-pointcuts-designators).

Comment: ok, thank you for support. It is as i thought. you confirmed my assumptions.